# How do I create a report with edit for every row in oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

everyone. I am working on a Oracle APEX application. I want to create a report with edit for every row. I followed that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqqcO1JKDdM but when I created the report strangely the "Edit-pencil" button opens a create form instead an edit. Does anyone have a clue what should I do to get the edit functionality? Thanks.

I looked many videos on youtube, but when I create a report like this: Create Page -> Report -> Report with Form -> and so on, I encounter the same problem - create form instead edit form.

Comment: Are you sure you want a report rather than an interactive grid?

Comment: Yes, I want a report with edit for each row. But instead edit I get a create dialog and I want an edit one

Answer (score 0):

> ... strangely the "Edit-pencil" button opens a create form instead an edit.

That's the same form (you use to create a new row and edit existing one). The only difference is the **link** you use; for editing, you have to go to IR's attributes and set which value you'll pass to the form (that would be the primary key, most probably).

[image]

Comment: In my APEX application I have another report where the same icon "Edit-pencil" leads to edit delete dialog and I want the same thing, but honestly that is my first apex application and I don't know how to achieve it

Comment: I told you; didn't you read what I wrote? Now I posted a screenshot as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I read, I don't understand. I followed your steps- 1, 2 , 3 and 4. I have name: P24_ID and value:\#ID#\. What should I change to enable editing?

Comment: Nothing; that's all - you set the link, pass ID value to Page 24. When you run the page and click the icon, it leads you to Page 24 and "loads" data related to that ID. Then you can edit those values and "Apply Changes" to save them.

Comment: Nothing happens it still the create form there not the edit

Comment: Sorry for asking, but - how do know the difference between the "create" and "edit" forms?

Comment: Create form- all the columns from the report , down right "create" button; edit form: all the field from the report populated with current row value, down right "apply changes" button and down left there is a "delete" button also

Comment: Right; that's it. If you - while pushing the "edit" icon see "create" form, check **server side conditions** for those buttons - they "decide" when will they be visible to you, Usually, they have e.g. "ITEM IS NOT NULL: P24_ID" and similar. If conditions look OK, then check whether you actually passed the ID value to the form (how? If it (the P24_ID) item is *hidden*, display it).

Comment: Where can I check this " server side conditions"? And thanks again for the help.

Comment: On Page 24, click e.g. CREATE button on left hand side. Then go to right hand side (where its properties are) and scroll down - you'll see "Server side condition" property.

Comment: I found "Server side condition" and played with it, no change yet. Where can I check if the  the P24_ID is hidden, I looked for that in the menus but I did no see it

Comment: Well, do you have P24_ID item on page 24? If you saw it on my screenshot, it doesn't mean you have it - you should set **your** primary key (page) item to appropriate value taken from the interactive report. Use lists of values (that's the button on the right hand side of each "field" in Link Builder window) and create valid pair of Page 24 item and report column.

Comment: I have this done. Page 23 is my report. And page 24 is the create form - this one that I want to make it an edit form. When I follow your picture I have this: name- P24_ID and value - \#ID#\ set by default

Comment: Don't accept defaults - I told you, pick items from lists of values.